# saveAsTextFile in Spark with header on each part file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to add a header to each part file produced by `saveAsTextFile`. One way I can think of doing so is to use `mapPartitionsWithIndex` instead of `saveAsTextFile` and write content to each part file myself while appending the header to each of those files. But is there a more elegant way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, if you need the partition index as well you can use `mapPartitionsWithIndex` instead:

```
rdd
  .mapPartitions(it => Iterator(Iterator("my header"), it).flatten)
  .saveAsTextFile
```